# TypeScript: Polymorfism with abstract methods

Tags: typescript, polymorphism, abstract-class

How can I make this work?

```
abstract class Animal {
    // No constructor
    ...    
    public abstract me():Animal;
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    // This fails! Why? Isn't every cat an Animal?
    me():Cat {
        return this;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Type 'this' is not assignable to type 'Animal'.

Comment: Works fine
http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=abstract%20class%20Animal%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20abstract%20me()%3AAnimal%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Cat%20extends%20Animal%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20me()%3ACat%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20cat%20%3D%20new%20Cat()%0D%0A%0D%0Acat.me()

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working. Turned out that if I don’t implement correctly every single method in the abstract class, typescript can’t tell if the child class extends the parent or not.

Other thing that was messing with me was the fact that a reference to ‘this’ inside a promise callback is not pointing to the actual object instance.